# BizTalk without Sql Server?

Tags: biztalk

Is it possible to use BizTalk without Sql Server ?

I mean with everything (MessageBox, SSO, config...) on the Oracle I already have?

It seems to me that all the Adapters are for external I/O, right?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. SQL Server is required for BizTalk Server Runtime, EDI, and BAM.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

BizTalk Server is a platform.  Part of that platform is SQL Server.  This just isn't sales pitch.  It has a good portion of its functionality built on SQL Server in the form of stored procs, scheduled jobs, DTC and more.  It would not be advisable, let alone possible, to easily port this over to Oracle.  I understand your thought process.  Many applications use the database tier as just a persistent storage mechanism.  BizTalk does not.

Comment: Nice answer - beyond the fact that so much of BizTalk is implemented using SQL server as the engine, the BizTalk engine also does some truly mystifying things under the covers that certainly wouldn't work on another database (e.g. I learned the other day that you *must* use a custom BizTalk process to reindex a BT database - updatestats won't work correctly!)

Comment: @ David Hall, could you provide more info on the "custom BizTalk process to reindex..." i'd sure be interested in knowing more about that.

Answer (score 1):

The adapters are feature exclusive for BizTalk. It is one of features that makes BizTalk so powerful.

I don't think there is a solution out there that allows you to only use the BizTalk adapters to interface with your existing EAI platform.

**As for the SQL server:**
BizTalk server **requires** Sql server for persisting messages, storing integration configuration, bindings, message tracking (if it is turned on), SSO, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the WCF adapters could work without BizTalk Server. Only license agreement prevent it usage without buying BTS. So if you have BTS license you can use WCF Adapter Pack with all adapters independently. 
There are detailed description and samples in the Adapter Pack Help how to use in in .NET code.